# How to send emails from multiple senders using SMTP in Python?

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime, smtplib

Trying to send out emails via SMTP from multiple people, and I feel like it'll save time if I don't have to quit the server and log back in for each person. This is the block I currently have:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login('Sender 1 Email','Sender 1 Password')
s.sendmail('Sender 1 Email','Receiver 1 Email',email1.as_string())
s.login('Sender 2 Email','Sender 2 Password')
s.sendmail('Sender 2 Email','Receiver 2 Email',email2.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Currently both emails are still coming from sender 1. Is there any way to change that without quitting the server between senders? Does SMTP have a log out attribute that I can't find? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Logging in as another user is not possible. You must call `quit()` and start over if you want to be a different sender.

Under the covers, the [login](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.login) function uses the SMTP AUTH command.

However, [RFC 4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954#section-4) states:

> After an AUTH command has been successfully completed, no more
> AUTH commands may be issued in the same session.  After a
> successful AUTH command completes, a server MUST reject any
> further AUTH commands

When you `quit()` and start over, you have a new session and can authenticate again (as the same user as previously, or a different user).

Your best option is to batch emails by sender account and then do one sender account after the other. You could look into multi-threading (as this is network i/o bound), and have a thread per sender.